# Vertical lines in table not in line

Tags: tables, line

I have the following table, but there are some lines that are not in one line. What would be the reason for that?

[image]

```
\begin{table}[htbp]
  \footnotesize
  \centering
  \caption{Add caption}
  \resizebox{\columnwidth}{!}{%
    \begin{tabular}{l|ll|ll|l|ll}
    \hline
    Row & \multicolumn{2}{l}{HPI} & \multicolumn{2}{|l}{CPUT} & \multicolumn{1}{|l}{FS\#} & \multicolumn{2}{|l}{GAP (\%)} \\ \cline{2-5} \cline{7-8}
    & [Min., Max.] & [Ave., Std.] & [Min., Max.] & [Ave., Std.] &  & [Min., Max.] & [Ave., Std.] \\ \hline
    \makecell[l]{Without \\ repair} & [0.78, 1] & [0.94, 0.06] & [0.59, 120] & [85.87, 42.87] & 120   & [0.11, 21.5] & [5.18, 5.86] \\ \hline
    \makecell[l]{With \\ repair} & [0.93, 1] & [0.99, 0.02] & [0.29, 22.96] & [5.18, 5.81] & 220   & [0, 2.5] & [0.14, 0.53] \\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}%
    }
  \label{tab:comp}%
\end{table}%
```

Answer (score 4):

Except for the first column, rules are at the right hand edge of the columns, so never do `\multicolumn{2}{|l}` always `\multicolumn{2}{l|}` otherwise, as you show, you will get a notch with part of the rule in the right and edge of one column and other parts in the left hand edge of the adjacent column.

Answer (score 1):

- Please always provide MWE (Minimal Working example, a complete small document,  which beside your problem inform us about page layout, which is defined by used document class and often by package `geometry` too.
- Don't scale table! This lead to inconsistent font sizes.
- Your problem is solved by @David Carlisle answer, however it can be (simple) avoided by use of the `tabularray` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[skip=1ex, font=small, labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[htbp]
    \small
\caption{Add caption}
\label{tab:comp}
    \begin{tblr}{hlines, 
                 colsep  = 5pt,
                 colspec = { Q[l,m] |Xl|Xl|c|Xl },
                } 
\SetCell[r=2]{l}  Row 
    & \SetCell[c=2]{l}  HPI     &   
        & \SetCell[c=2]{l}  CPUT    &   
            & \SetCell[r=2]{l}  FS\# 
                & \SetCell[c=2]{l}  GAP (\%)    
                    &                               \\
    & [Min., Max.] & [Ave., Std.]   
        & [Min., Max.]  & [Ave., Std.]
            &       & [Min., Max.]  & [Ave., Std.]  \\
{Without \\ repair} 
    & [0.78, 1] & [0.94, 0.06] 
        & [0.59, 120]   & [85.87, 42.87] 
            & 120   & [0.11, 21.5]  & [5.18, 5.86]  \\
{With \\ repair} 
    & [0.93, 1] & [0.99, 0.02] 
        & [0.29, 22.96] & [5.18, 5.81] 
            & 220   & [0, 2.5]      & [0.14, 0.53] \\
    \end{tblr}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

*Note*: `tabularray` package

- gives also better vertical centering of cells contents
- use different command names for multi row and multi column cells:

  - for multirow:  `\SetCell[r=<number of rows>] {<align>} <content>`
  - for multicolumn: `\SetCell[c=<number of columns>] {<align>} <content>`
- for more details please consult the package documentation

[image]

Comment: @Imran, thank you correcting explanation!